# Trippinin api Keyerror

Tags: api, python-3.x, keyerror

I need som help to get started with this trippinin api, if you have worked with this api it would be very nice of you to just help me here to get started! I dont understand what I should write in for dayin data[....]:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("http://api.v1.trippinin.com/City/London/Eat?day=monday&time=morning&limit=10& offset=2&KEY=58ffb98334528b72937ce3390c0de2b7")
data = r.json()

for day in data['city Name']:
    print (day['city Name']['weekday'] + ":")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nux\Desktop\Kurs3\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    for day in data['city Name']:
KeyError: 'city Name'
```

Comment: Show us the actual error/full backtrace. Is 'city Name' causing the KeyError, or 'weekday'? And have you tried printing `data` itself, to what it contains?

Comment: Its the ['city Name'] thats giving me a key Error. The print function atm is just something i wrote before I tested it so I dont know if that will work either Im kinda new to this so...

Comment: Did you print `data` itself? I just put the URL in my browser, and from a quick glance, `city Name` and `weekday` are not even keys.

Comment: In fact, since the city name and weekday are *input*, it looks like trippinin will simply not give you back your input as output. You already have those values, so they don't need to be in data (and thus, aren't).

Comment: Okay Evert the error code is in the post now! If they are not keys what are? haha I feel really stupid now

Answer (score 0):

The error `KeyError: 'X'` means you are trying to access the key `X` in a dictionary, but it doesn't exist. In your case you're trying to access `data['city Name']`. Apparently, the information in `data` does not have the key `city Name`. That means either a) you aren't getting *any* data back, or b) the data isn't in the format you expected. In both cases you can validate (or invalidate) your assumptions by printing out the value of `data`.

To help debug this issue, add the following immediately after you assign a value to data:

```
print(data)
```